# How can i disable some item in optgroup

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

**How can i disable some item in optgroup**

i want to disable "--Pick Up--" and "--All locations--" i am using drorpdwon

```
<select name="ddlpickuplocation" id="ddlpickuplocation" tabindex="1" class="width320">
<optgroup label="california">
<option value="--Pick Up--">--Pick Up--</option>
<option value="LOS ANGELES AIRPORT  (LAX)">LOS ANGELES AIRPORT  (LAX)</option>
<option value="SAN DIEGO AIRPORT  (SAN)">SAN DIEGO AIRPORT  (SAN)</option>
<option value="SAN FRANCISCO AIRPORT  (SFO)">SAN FRANCISCO AIRPORT  (SFO)</option>
<option value="--All locations--">--All locations--</option>
<option value="ANAHEIM DOWNTOWN">ANAHEIM DOWNTOWN</option>
<option value="BATON ROUGE INTERNATIONAL AIRPORT">BATON ROUGE INTERNATIONAL AIRPORT</option>
<option value="BERKELEY DOWNTOWN">BERKELEY DOWNTOWN</option>
<option value="SAN JOSE AIRPORT">SAN JOSE AIRPORT</option>
<option value="SANTA BARBARA AIRPORT">SANTA BARBARA AIRPORT</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="florida">
<option value="BOCA RATON AIRPORT">BOCA RATON AIRPORT</option>
<option value="CLEARWATER AIRPORT">CLEARWATER AIRPORT</option>
<option value="DAYTONA AIRPORT">DAYTONA AIRPORT</option>

</optgroup>


</optgroup>
<optgroup label="rest of usa">
<option value="--Pick Up--">--Pick Up--</option>
<option value="CHICAGO OHARE AIRPORT  (ORD)">CHICAGO OHARE AIRPORT  (ORD)</option>
<option value="--All locations--">--All locations--</option>
<option value="AKRON AIRPORT">AKRON AIRPORT</option>
<option value="ALLENTOWN AIRPORT">ALLENTOWN AIRPORT</option>
<option value="ALLENTOWN DOWNTOWN">ALLENTOWN DOWNTOWN</option>
<option value="AMARILLO AIRPORT">AMARILLO AIRPORT</option>
<option value="ANCHORAGE AIRPORT">ANCHORAGE AIRPORT</option>
<option value="ANDERSON DOWNTOWN">ANDERSON DOWNTOWN</option>
<option value="APPLETON AIRPORT">APPLETON AIRPORT</option>
<option value="ARKANUS AIRPORT">ARKANUS AIRPORT</option>
<option value="ATLANTA AIRPORT">ATLANTA AIRPORT</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="western usa">
<option value="ALBUQUERQUE AIRPORT">ALBUQUERQUE AIRPORT</option>
<option value="ASPEN AIRPORT">ASPEN AIRPORT</option>

</optgroup>
```

Answer (score 1):

use attribute selector `[]`

try this

```
$('option[value="--Pick Up--"]').prop('disabled',true);
$('option[value="--All locations--"]').prop('disabled',true);
```

Comment: check this fiddle   http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/M6Aju/ ..if you check the options it is disabled

Comment: hi its work but my dropdwon is inside the update panel. due to update panel it give me problam. plz suggest any answer

Answer (score 1):

Add `disabled` attribute to those options:

```
<option value="--Pick Up--" disabled>--Pick Up--</option>
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to do it with JavaScript, you can do as bipen did in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16236469/1816426)

```
$('#ddlpickuplocation option[value="--Pick Up--"]').prop('disabled',true);
$('#ddlpickuplocation option[value="--All locations--"]').prop('disabled',true);
```

However, for the first time the first option will be selected by default, so you can also add code to change the initial selection. Check [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t72MA/).

Comment: hi its work but my dropdwon is inside the update panel. due to update panel it give me problam. plz suggest any answer

Comment: @KamleshKumarSaini you have to update your question with more code and write what problems you have. No-one will be able to answer your question without that.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want option to be disabled due to styling, just use optgroup again. Something like

```
<select>
   <optgroup label="rest of usa">
        <optgroup label="--Pick Up--"></optgroup>
        <option value="CHICAGO OHARE AIRPORT  (ORD)">CHICAGO OHARE AIRPORT  (ORD)</option>
        <option value="--All locations--">--All locations--</option>
        <option value="AKRON AIRPORT">AKRON AIRPORT</option>
   </optgroup>
</select>
```